# While printing objects of `Set` nothing get printed on console

Tags: flutter, set

I'm trying to print the result after performing some operation on object of `Set` class.

The code I've tried so far...

```
void main() {

 final t1 = TwoWheeler("Honda", "CB Shine", 4);
 final t2 = TwoWheeler("Honda", "Twister", 4);
 final t3 = TwoWheeler("Hero", "Splendar", 4);
 final t4 = TwoWheeler("Bajaj", "Pulser", 5);

 List list = [t1, t2, t3, t4];

 var result = list.map( (ss) {
  return ss.gear < 5 ? ss.desc() : null;
 });
 print("2-wheeler with 4 gears are $result"); //The result is get printed as I want

 var set = new Set<String>();
 set = result.toSet();
 print("2-wheeler with 4 gears are $set"); //Nothing printed on console

 set.removeWhere( (ss) => ss != null);
 print("2-wheeler with 4 gears are $set"); //Nothing printed on console

}
```

**Output**

```
2-wheeler with 4 gears are (Honda CB Shine with 4 gear(s), Honda Twister with 4 gear(s), Hero Splendar with 4 gear(s), null)

//Other 2 print statement is not displaying anything.
```

Am I missing something? Even compiler not complaining for the issue.

I'm using [Dart Pad](https://dartpad.dev)

Comment: it works just fine (even on dartpad), tried to use normal dev environment?

Comment: I'm using dart pad online and I don't know about setting env. to dart pad.

Comment: use android studio or vscode with flutter installation

Comment: what do you see when running this: `var arr = [1, 33, 555];
  print(arr);
  var mapped = arr.map((i) => i <= 100? i.toString() : null);
  print(mapped);
  var set = new Set<String>();
  set = mapped.toSet();
  print(set);` ? is it: `[1, 33, 555]
(1, 33, null)
{1, 33, null}` ?

Comment: Here is the output: `[1, 33, 555]
(1, 33, null)
{1, 33, null}`

Comment: so it works: first output is int `List`, next one is mapped to string `Iterable` and the last is `Set`

Comment: so what is the source of the problem? do I need to set anything on dart pad like some configuration or setting env. or some thing else.

Comment: i dont know: run it in a full offline flutter environment - do you have flutter installed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203586/discussion-between-mahendra-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this and let me know is it working or not !

```
 var result = list.where( (ss) {
             return ss.gear < 5;
            });
 print("2-wheeler with 4 gears are $result");

 var set = Set.from(result);
 print("2-wheeler with 4 gears are $set"); //Nothing printed on console

 set.removeWhere( (ss) => ss != '');
 print("2-wheeler with 4 gears are $set");
```

Comment: No it is neither List<String> nor List<TwoWheeler> as It contains `null` at end.

Comment: Its because you are adding null if condition mismatched ! I edited my code. Check it

Comment: What result you are expecting ?

Comment: The final output should be List<TwoWheeler> without null value

Comment: My answer is showing empty list without any null value !

Comment: @Mahendra if you want something without null value simply do not add that `null`: use `where()` for example

Comment: Nice hint @pskink. Thanks.

Comment: This is what I exactly want. The `where` method.

Comment: The above code is also do the same !! But using where is better !